# ListAPIView with JSONRenderer returns text/html

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-drf-renderer

Straightforward question, I am using DRF with a class-based view to serve up an API for consumption by Angular. In particular, I want to respond to a GET request with JSON data that Angular can subscribe to:

```
class AuditListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Audit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuditSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = AuditFilter
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
```

The problem is that the content type for the response is "text/html" instead of "application/json". For example:

```
> curl -s -I <host>:8000 | grep "^Content-Type:"
Content-Type: text/html
```

Can anyone explain why this is so, and how to address this?

Comment: The call itself is not giving any errors? e.g. a 404 not found.

Comment: Can you show your URLs? Are you sure the request is going to the right view?

Comment: Can you give the output of `curl -X GET <host>:8000`